# Git: send-email without commit

Tags: git, email, commit, git-send-email

I have a project where I made changes, and want to send them to another user, using git send-email feature.

I found that it works by sending patches (created by `git format-patch` of each commit).

Is it able to send just `diff`'s ? I don't want to commit first, and then send the patch.

Does git `format-patch` or maybe `send-email`  have some parameter to just do that quickly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you want to commit? that's real cheap. create a branch for that commit if you don't want to commit to your "main" branch

Comment: @Mat commit and tried to send-email, but raised this error: Command unknown: 'AUTH' at /usr/lib/git-core/git-send-email. Know anything about it?

Comment: @Mat found what was wrong. Answered. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out not to be possible. So I commited and tried to `send-email` it, which throws an error

> Command unknown: 'AUTH' at /usr/lib/git-core/git-send-email

This error is related to my smtp-server not supporting authentication.

To solve this, I commented the line in my `.gitconfig` where it says `smtpuser,` so that it doesn't pass any user or password to git. Then, the email gets sent without a problem.

But I still think that should have an option to use `send-email` feature, sending a patch without having to commit it first.

Comment: I suspect this is a conscious design decision as git usually tries very hard not to lose any of your code. Imagine you sent out the diff without committing, and then changed something. Now the person looking at the diff is actually looking at an inconsistent state of your repo because the source of the diff is no longer there.

Comment: The logic of send-email is to send a couple of commits with sensible commit messages. If you want to send a diff, you can simply use `git diff | mail`. It's so easy to create a commit, though that I don't think this is an issue at all.