# "STARTTLS is required to send mail" error with git send-email when using an outlook email

Tags: git, email

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and initially, I did not have `git send-email` as a valid command. I installed `git-email` and then `git send-email` started working.

I have the following config file:

```
[sendemail]
    # smtpuser = <myemail@outlook.com>
    from = My Name <myemail@outlook.com>
    smtpserver = smtp.office365.com
    smtpencryption = STARTTLS
    smtpserverport = 587
```

When I run `git send-email --to <myemail@outlook.com> patches/*.patch` to test it and send the respective patches to *my* email, I get the following output:

```
5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send mail [ZR0P278CA0106.CHEP278.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

I got the SMTP server, the encryption method, and the server port from outlook's website from my e-mail settings.

P.S.: I have `smtpuser` commented out because I was getting an error that is solved, by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6444339/8324585) answer, by removing the `smtpuser` field.

Comment: According to [the `git send-email` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email), the setting to tell it to use TLS encryption is `smtpencryption = tls`, not `smptencryption = STARTTLS`. I have not tried this myself though.

Comment: @torek I've tried using tls but it does not work. The encryption method, gotten from Outlook's website is STARTTLS.

Comment: STARTTLS is used on port 25.  Port 587 uses TLS from the get go.